# Integrating $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln t}{t^2+a^2}\,dt$ with residue theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus, discrete-logarithms

I want to calculate

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln t}{t^2+a^2}\,dt$$

using the Residue Theorem. The contour I want to use is almost the upper half circle of radius $R$, but going around $0$ following a half-circle of radius $\epsilon$, and using the branch cut at $7\pi/8$. The picture is below.

[image]

Comment: So you want to calculate, and want to use... and what is your question?

Comment: I would like to learn the usage differences of $3\pi/2$. and $7\pi/8$. branches.

Comment: *Is* there a branch cut at $7\pi/8$? Can you prove that?